# Synchronisation failed, dropping peer valid and Impossible reorg

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I'm working on a project called [Rubykube Workbench](https://github.com/rubykube/workbench). But the "ethereum/client-go:Stable" container gives error.

**System information**

Geth version: `1.8.23-stable-c9427004` (docker container)
OS & Version: Ubuntu 14.04 (Hyper - V)
Project-Commit : (RubyKube Workbench - 658c806`)

**Expected behaviour**

[image]

**Actual behaviour**

It doesn't look ethereum here. (0)

[image]

ethereum/client-go:Stable log
[image]

**Thank You :)**